# Applying multiple transforms to the PCollection :: Error WriteToBigQuery

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I hope someone can help me as I'm at a dead-end now  I'm learning's Apache Beam and working on a streaming pipeline (Python 3.7, apache-beam v 2.15, DirectRunner for now) reading from PubSub source.

Applying multiple transforms process to the same PCollection to produces multiple outputs to ultimately sink the output into to 2 different BQ tables.

However, when I run the pipeline it seems each of these transforms are are influencing each other (by mutating element) and thus causing a schema mismatch when executing bigquery.WriteToBigQuery transform

Each PubSub message, along with message attributes is formatted as follows:

`{'data': json.dumps({ "key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}).encode(),
'attributes':{'evt_time': '2019-09-14T22:12:43.323546Z'}}`

Id like to read these messages and dump to 2 BQ tables:

- table1 `raw_table` schema: `evt_time,date` (storing raw data along with event_time extracted from message attribute) `{'evt_time': '2019-09-14T22:12:43.323546Z', 'payload': '{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}'}`
- table2 `parsed_table` schema: `evt_time,key1,key2` (parsing & storing each KV pair in the data as a flat table along with event_time extracted form message attribute) `{'evt_time': '2019-09-14T22:12:43.323546Z', 'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}`

this my pseudo code so far

1) 
message is read into pipeline and then apply map transform which essentially extracts `data` to `payload` field and `evt_time` to `evt_time` field

```py
row = p 
| "read_sub" >> beam.Create([ {'data': json.dumps({ "key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}).encode(),
'attributes':{'evt_time': '2019-09-14T22:12:43.323546Z'}}])
| "add_timestamps" >> beam.Map(add_timestamps)`
```

2)
I then store `row` into table1 `raw_table`

```py
row | "raw_stream_to_bq" >>bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(project = PROJECT,
 dataset = BQ_DATASET, table ="test_raw", schema=SCHEMA_RAW_TABLE)
```

3) apply further parsing to `row` extracting KV pair before strong each message element to table2 `parsed_table`

```py
row | "parse" >> beam.Map(parse_payload) \
    | "parsed_stream_to_bq" >> bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(project=PROJECT, 
dataset=BQ_DATASET, table="test_parsed", schema=SCHEMA_PARSED_TABLE)
```

following map functions `add_timestamps` and `parse_payload` are defined as follows:

```py
def add_timestamps(e,timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam, *args,**kwargs):
        payload = e['data'].decode()
        evt_time = e['attributes']['evt_time']
        row = {'evt_time' : evt_time, 'payload' : payload}
        return row
def parse_payload(e,timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam, *args,**kwargs):
        payload = json.loads(e.pop('payload'))
        e.update(payload)
        return e
```

However when I run the pipeline it gives BQ streaming insert error as below, and I get the feeling due to downstream step #3, each message row  element is already getting parsed / mutated when step#2 BQ write transform is applied and thus BQ streaming insets in step #2 fails due to schema mismatch.

> Errors are [
>
> errors: [
>
> debugInfo: ''
>
> location: 'key1'
>
> message: 'no such field.'
>
> reason: 'invalid'>]
>
> index: 0>]

**UPDATE**:

1) when I use `WriteToText` transform instead of `WriteToBigQuery` it works fine, as expected

- step #1 output: `{'evt_time': '2019-09-14T22:12:43.323546Z', 'payload': '{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}'}`
- step #3 map transform output: `{'evt_time': '2019-09-14T22:12:43.323546Z', 'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}`

2) HOWEVER when using `WriteToBigQuery` both above steps output same parsed KV pairs `{'evt_time': '2019-09-14T22:12:43.323546Z', 'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}`

**UPDATE 2 - RESOLVED**

I did two changes after @Guillem suggestions below (and it also works on DirectRunner now)

3) avoid modifying elements in-place

4) removed `schema=` parameter from `bigquery.WriteToBigQuery` transforms and pre-build BQ tables before launching the pipeline after noticing following errors sometimes during first write

> File “/PATH_TO_PY/python3.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 604, in __ProcessHttpResponse
>
> http_response, method_config=method_config, request=request)
>   apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpConflictError: HttpError accessing https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/arctic-rite-234823/datasets/pipeline/tables?alt=json: response: <{'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Mon, 16 Sep 2019 02:52:35 GMT', 'server': 'ESF', 'cache-control': 'private', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'status': '409', 'content-length': '334', '-content-encoding': 'gzip'}>, content <{
>
> "error": {
>
> "code": 409,
>
> "message": "Already Exists: Table PROJECT_ID:DATASET_ID.TABLE_ID”,
>
> "errors": [
>
> ```
>  {
>
>    "message": "Already Exists: Table PROJECT_ID:DATASET_ID.TABLE_ID",
>
>    "domain": "global",
>
>    "reason": "duplicate"
>
>  }
> ```
>
> ],
>
> "status": "ALREADY_EXISTS"
>
> }

Answer (score 1):

Commenting out the second write allows the first one to succeed so it seems to be an issue with `parse_payload` and the `DirectRunner`.

To fix it you can avoid modifying elements in-place by making a copy inside the `Map` function:

```py
def parse_payload(element,timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam, *args,**kwargs):
        e = element.copy()
        payload = json.loads(e.pop('payload'))
        e.update(payload)
        return e
```

It works well without changes using the `DataflowRunner`:

[image]

as the graph is constructed as expected (two separate branches):

[image]

Full repro [code](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/8e759a41421e93ab77d46c72e1adf808).

Comment: Thank for your suggestions. RESOLVED, See **Update 2** above, working [code](https://github.com/vibhorj/gcp/blob/master/df/so-57940102/pipeline.py). It works but I don't still get **#3)** I thought each Transforms is immutable, and thus any changes downstream should bot affect elements in upstream steps **#4)** it seems multiple workers at same time try create a new table, if it doesn't exist and thus the error...